# php path, cron and cpanel

Tags: cron

I've spent days still can't figure out this.

I have following file structure under public_html:

```
cron_jobs/file.php contains - > include('../base/basefile.php')
base/basefile.php contains - > include('baseSubFile.php')
```

when I run

`/pathtophp/php -f ~/public_html/cron_jobs/file.php`

it works ok but when I copy the same command to cron in cpanel, I get error saying

`'basesubfile.php' can't be found`

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Cron won't run from the same directory as your php file is in, so you'll need to change to it first:

```
cd /home/user/public_html/cron_jobs/ && /pathtophp/php -f file.php
```

I recommend the full path versus `~` when dealing with cron scripts to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

You should used

```
include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../base/basefile.php';
```

and

```
include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/baseSubFile.php';
```

[The function dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) returns parent directory's path

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this at the top of your PHP script:

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```